# Recognize string on excel

Tags: excel

I have a lot of columns with some names on an excel file. 
I want to put "1" in an empty cell if in the cell there are the letters "srl". Is there an excel formula to do this?

Comment: There are several. Look at Excel Help for `FIND` and `SEARCH`.  If you have problems with your formula, post back with the problem well outlined and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. Before you do that, you should also read [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are in `column A`, enter the below formula in `column B`,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("srl",A1)),1,"")
```

This would put a `1`, if `srl` is found, if not just blanks.

[image]